# How to clear elements on array beacause clear is not working?

Tags: c#, arrays

This is my code, but `clear` method is not working, but I can't find the error.
This is the first time that clear method it's not working, anyone can help me?

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
public class test{ 
    public static void Main() 
    { 
        try {  
            int[] myArr = {-1, 4, 8, 6}; 
            PrintIndexAndValues(myArr); 
            Console.WriteLine(); 

            Console.WriteLine("Taking index out of bound:"); 
            Array.clear(myArr, 1, 2); 
            Console.WriteLine("Array After Operation:"); 
            PrintIndexAndValues(myArr); 
        } 

    } 
    public static void PrintIndexAndValues(int[] myArr) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < myArr.Length; i++) { 
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", myArr[i]); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `using system` is it java code?

Comment: That's C#. But shouldn't it be `Array.Clear()`? Capital C. And please be more specific than "not working".

Comment: yes sorry, i've edited the tag :-)

Comment: What are you seeing, and what are you expecting? Wouldn't `Array.Clear(myArr, 1, 2)` remove elements 1 and 2 (so 4 and 8 in your case) leaving -1 and 6?

Comment: [Documentation for `Array.Clear`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clear?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: `Array.Clear()` does not remove items from an array. It _Sets a range of elements in an array to the default value of each element type._

Comment: @mrblewog yes, however, I had written Array.clear with lowercase

Comment: @aleks.ko so you did -- and what does your code print out?

Comment: @mrblewog 4 and 8

Comment: @aleks.ko and what do you expect to see?

Comment: @mrblewog it's right, 4 and 8

Comment: Your final output should be - `Array After Operation:
-1
0
0
6`. Basically resetting 2 array elements from index 1

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/):

> The number of dimensions and the length of each dimension are established when the array instance is created. These values can't be changed during the lifetime of the instance.

If you want to be able to use Clear() the way you inted to, you should use a List instead:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>{-1, 4, 8, 6};

// Do some stuff with your list

myList.Clear();
```

Edit:
Your PrintIndexAndValues actually only prints the values, here's how you could do it instead:

```
public static void PrintIndexAndValues(List<int> myList) 
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, myList[i]);
    }
```

Edit2: Just realized that you probably wanted to remove the first and last element of the array, not clear the whole array?
This should do the trick:

```
myList.RemoveAt(3)
myList.RemoveAt(0)
```

Comment: You'd have to do the `RemoveAt(3)` first because after you remove the first item the size of the list will be different, or better yet `myList.RemoveAt(myList.Count - 1)` to make sure you are removing the last item.

Comment: Thaaaat is absolutely correct, thanks! I edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following is your corrected code

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 

public class Test
{ 
    public static void Main() 
    { 
            int[] myArr = {-1, 4, 8, 6}; 

            PrintIndexAndValues(myArr); 
            Console.WriteLine(); 

            Console.WriteLine("Taking index out of bound:"); 
            Array.Clear(myArr, 0, myArr.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Array After Operation:"); 
            PrintIndexAndValues(myArr); 
    } 

    public static void PrintIndexAndValues(int[] myArr) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < myArr.Length; i++)  
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", myArr[i]); 
    } 
}
```

This will set ALL values in your array to 0.